# How to conditionally modify Apache response header 'Location'

Tags: apache, header, response, mod-headers

I need to be able to test the URL string in a Location response header for a certain pattern and if it matches replace it with another.

e.g. if response is Location: http://wrongserver.com I need to change it to Location: http://rightserver.com

Seems mod_setenvif only operates on request headers so I haven't been able to combine this with a "Header set" directive to achieve what I want.

Content is not being proxied so using mod_proxy directives doesn't seem to be an option.

Thanks,
Bernie

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to do this with `mod_headers`

```
Header edit Location ^http://wrongserver.com$ http://rightserver.com
```

More info here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header

Comment: Many thanks - I was looking at an earlier spec for mod_headers - before edit was added - doh!

Comment: To keep the query string when specified, you can add this one  : 
Header edit Location ^http://wrongserver.com/(.*)$ http://rightserver.com/$1

Comment: @PrShadoko If you don't use `$`, then the regex only matches the hostname and the remainder of the URL should stay untouched. The only "edit" example in the [mod_headers documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#examples) demonstrates this kind of thing (they replace `https:` protocol with `http:`).